# polymer to develop web application

Tags: web-applications, polymer

I am about to develop a complex web app for business purposes and i was looking into the different technologies available.
Has someone developed a web app based entirely on Polymer?
Do you think Polymer is mature enough to be used for that purpose and could you provide some feedback from your experience?

Many thanks!

Comment: Definitely mature enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Definitely** I'll suggest you to use **polymer** for your project.

With the 1.0 release of its Polymer library, Google is pushing for a method of building Web applications that leverages the development of interoperable custom elements.

So if you are looking for a fast and easy way to get started building a production-ready web application using Polymer? Use the [Polymer starter kit](https://github.com/polymerelements/polymer-starter-kit). Packed with the latest elements, ready-to-use boilerplate, and an end-to-end toolchain to use from development through production deployment, the starter kit works out of the box so you can focus on adding features right away.

Additionally, check out the many brand-new element product lines built by the Polymer team with the [Polymer elements catalog](https://elements.polymer-project.org). There you can browse for elements to help create or add features to your web app - whether you need buttons or layouts, Google maps or push notifications. For just about any problem you might need to solve on the web, there’s an element for that.

Also you can look at the web applications made with polymer here -

1. https://builtwithpolymer.org
2. https://madewithpolymer.com

To understand more about the state of polymer you can look at the [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PbYvv2VUp90&list=PLNYkxOF6rcICdISJclfQhj2S8QZGjXV8J) of [Google Polymer summit 2015](https://www.polymer-project.org/summit)

Answer (score 2):

**Definitely**.
Have a look here: [crowdaboutnow.nl](https://crowdaboutnow.nl/). It's entirely written in Polymer. There are some hurdles to overcome when building entire web applications with WebComponents. But in the end we're quite content with it.